# Eclipse: Project 'PROJECT_NAME' has no explicit encoding set

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I downgraded from Windows 11 to Windows 10 today and had to reinstall the Eclipse-IDE.
After successfully importing my workspaces and fixing the projects, a warning appeared for every project saying "Project XXX has no explicit encoding set". I've already searched for a solution and only got some fixes for VSCode.

I had **Eclipse 2021-6** and installed **Eclipse 2022-6**

Comment: Selecting the warning in the _Problems_ view and hitting Ctrl+1 provides you a Quick Fix. Or change the project manually in _Project > Properties: Resource_. For details see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.24/platform.php#no-explicit-encoding-project-warning and/or watch my video https://youtu.be/zDJtVYAJwyY?t=663

Comment: The above from @howlger is an "Answer" not a question aimed at further clarification.

Comment: Funny why you downgraded from W11 to W10. In my case I upgraded from Winblows to Linux =)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, the [**warning for projects with no explicit default encoding** is a **new** thing in **Eclipse 2022-06** (4.24)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.24/platform.php#no-explicit-encoding-project-warning).

To set an explicit default encoding do one of the following:

- In the ***Problems* view, select the warning**, hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>** and apply the provided Quick Fix (sets the project encoding explicitly to the workspace encoding)
- Change the project manually in ***Project > Properties: Resource***

See also [my video showing and explaining this](https://youtu.be/zDJtVYAJwyY?t=663).

When using a build system like Maven or Gradle, set the encoding as follows instead:

**Maven**

1. In `pom.xml` set the property `project.build.sourceEncoding` to `UTF-8`:

   ```
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Right-click the project folder and choose ***Maven > Update Project...***

**Gradle**

1. In `build.gradle` set `compileJava.options.encoding` to `UTF-8`:

   ```
   compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
   ```
2. Right-click the project folder and choose ***Gradle > Refresh Gradel Project***
3. As long as [Eclipse Buildship issue #344](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/344) is not fixed, change the encoding manually as described above

Comment: I have a Maven project and every time I run `Update Project` it gives me the encoding set message. Is there a way to specify it in the `pom.xml`?

Comment: @CardinalSystem See the answer I just posted.

Comment: @JoséErnestoLaraRodríguez This would have been better a comment or an addition to an existing answer rather than another answer of its own.

Comment: Eclipse is dumb then, because I'm inheriting that `compileJava` option from a higher-level gradle as in `apply from: "$projectDir/settings.gradle"` and it still cannot find it.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Follow the link and provide a pull request.

Comment: in macOS the quick fix is initiated with CMD-1 or CMD(right) click and select quick fix.

Answer (score 14):

If you prefer to ignore this warning for all projects you can change the preferences:

> General -> Workspace -> Report missing project encoding as: **Ignore**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Maven, every time you run "Update project" the warning comes back, as the project configuration is re-created from the POM file. To get rid of this warning permanently, add this in your POM file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Then, run "Update project" and the warning is gone.
You can find more info here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, add something similar to the following to your `pom.xml`:

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.resources.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this part of Eclipse settings (through eclipse task in Gradle, for example), create a file named "org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs" in .settings folder with these contents -

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
encoding/<project>=UTF-8
```

This would be the command in gradle's eclipse task -

```
new File(".settings", "org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs").text = """eclipse.preferences.version=1
encoding/<project>=UTF-8
"""
```